# Are there ways to knock smaller opponents back a distance greater than 10' without grappling or spells?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

The Monster Manual makes mention of the Awesome Blow monster feat (p. 303) that allows you to knock smaller opponents back 10' with a well-placed hit. But from what I can tell this is the only way to knock an enemy back some distance using a creature's own power. This might be interesting for a creature that's 10' tall itself (dwarves in plate armor are notoriously heavy and unaerodynamic, so kicking one 10' away is quite a feat), but when you are a Huge creature of above average size (24' to 32') this is rather pitiful.

Are there any other ways to increase this distance? I am looking for things that allow a creature of sufficient size knock smaller opponents back over a considerable distance without the use of spells or grappling and throwing. So things like feats, natural abilities or special abilities inherent to a creature and other such things. I'd preferably not look at stuff that involves taking character classes unless this is the only way to pull something like this off. Note that I am looking for these things usable for monsters rather than players.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## *Races of Stone*’s Knockback feat

Knockback requires Power Attack, Improved Bull Rush, and Large or larger size. With it, any Power Attack you successfully make allows you to follow it up with a free Bull Rush attempt, to which you get a bonus equal to the Power Attack damage bonus. This provokes no attacks of opportunity, and most importantly, **you do not move with your target that you knock backward.**

This is a normal bull rush, so the distance your target moves is based on how much you succeed on the bull rush check by. Strength and size are the principle ways to improve that.

All three feats are Fighter bonus feats, by the way, in case that’s useful to you, but as feats you don’t *need* Fighter levels. If you have them, the Dungeoncrasher ACF from *Dungeonscape* fits in really well.

Comment: Can you use Knockback in addition to Bull Rush or do they have to be used seperately in seperate turns (because Knockback involves a standard action and a Bull Rush is a full-round action)?

Comment: @ThomasJacobs Knockback provides a free bull rush attempt following a successful attack made using Power Attack, much the same way as one can get a free trip after an attack by either using [Knock-down](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/divine/divineAbilitiesFeats.htm#knockDown) or being a [wolf](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/wolf.htm).

Comment: I houseruled that the same numeric effects apply to awesome blow. Makes no sense for a colossal sized dragon to only send someone flying as far as a medium sized goliath.

Comment: @KRyan Alright, but you can't use a Power Attack as part of a Charge or Bull Rush, right?

Comment: @ThomasJacobs Power Attack can be applied to any attack (or set of attacks, for cases like a full-attack). Since charging involves an attack, you can Power Attack at the end of it (and there are feats that specifically empower that particular maneuver, e.g. Shock Trooper from *Complete Warrior*). A typical bull rush, on the other hand, involves no attacks, and therefore Power Attack does not apply.

Comment: @ThomasJacobs With Knockback, *any attack* that you choose to apply Power Attack to (e.g. at the end of a charge, each of the attacks in a full-attack) is followed by an opposed bull rush check, giving you the opportunity to knock the foe back. In *this* form, Power Attack *does* benefit the bull rush check, gaining a bonus equal to the damage bonus from Power Attack.

Answer (score 1):

#### A monster could employ the Setting Sun martial discipline's throw maneuvers

The feat Martial Study (*Tome of Battle* 31-2) grants a creature the ability 1/encounter to use a maneuver picked when the feat is picked. The creature must meet the maneuver's prerequisites, but the feat Martial Study can be picked thrice. The following martial maneuvers (with their parenthetical prerequisites) hurl foes around the battlefield:

- Mighty Throw (HD 2) hurls a creature up to 10 ft. away.
- Devastating Throw (HD 10 and 1 Setting Sun maneuver) hurls a creature up to 10 ft. or more away.
- Comet Throw (HD 14 and 1 Setting Sun maneuver) hurls a creature up to 10 ft. or more away.
- Soaring Throw (HD 18 and 2 Setting Sun maneuvers) hurls a creature up to 15 ft. or more away.
- Ballista Throw (HD 22 and 2 Setting Sun maneuvers) hurls a creature up to 60 ft. away.

I've found the feat Martial Study particularly good for monsters due to the relatively small feat investment for a rather large return (especially on monsters that advance by Hit Dice into insanity like undead and aberrations). Considering most monsters' short table lives, it's rarely an issue that the monster can only use its maneuver once per encounter.